# Error in conforming to a protocol defined in Objective from swift code

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have the following header for ReaderViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ReaderDocument.h"

@class ReaderViewController;

@protocol ReaderViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional // Delegate protocols

- (void)dismissReaderViewController:(ReaderViewController *)viewController;

@end

@interface ReaderViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak, readwrite) id <ReaderViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (instancetype)initWithReaderDocument:(ReaderDocument *)object;

@end
```

In a swift file

```
  class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Get the row data for the selected row
    var phrase: String = "" ;

    var document:ReaderDocument? = ReaderDocument(filePath: "/Users/Krishna/Development/XXXX/Reader.pdf", password: phrase);
    if(document != nil){
        var readerViewController:ReaderViewController  = ReaderViewController(readerDocument: document)
        readerViewController.delegate = self ;
        readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve;
        readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen;
        self.presentViewController(readerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func dismissReaderViewController(viewController: ReaderViewController) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}


}
```

For the line readerViewController.delegate = self ; Xcode throws a compile time exception that

Type 'DetailTableViewController' does not conform to protocol 'ReaderViewControllerDelegate' . 
I tried looking for solutions for other similar posts and couldn't figure out the issue. 
Any help is appreciated as I am new developer in iOS platform!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `ReaderViewControllerDelegate` to the first line in your `DetailTableViewController`, as this tells the compiler, that this class conforms to the particular delegate protocol.

```
class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ReaderViewControllerDelegate
```

Comment: Your welcome :) Please mark this answer as accepted (green checkmark), to close this issue. Thank you.